# OpenCV FileStorage with Empty Output (Visual Studio 2013)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I wonder anyone has faced a problem showing empty output when using the FileStorage in OpenCV? I am following the exact tutorial and other sample code, however the output is just always empty array. Below shows my .yaml file and main.cpp.

YAML file as below:

```
    %YAML:1.0
    A: !!opencv-matrix
    rows: 3
    cols: 3
    dt: f
    data: [ 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]
```

Main.cpp file as below:

```
    int main(int argc, char * const argv[])
    {
    Mat var1;
    Mat var2;

    string demoFile = "C:\\faceData\\demo.yaml";

    FileStorage fsDemo(demoFile, FileStorage::READ);
    fsDemo["A"] >> var1;
    fsDemo["A"] >> var2;

    cout << "Print the contents of var1:" << endl;
    cout << var1 << endl << endl;

    cout << "Print the contents of var2:" << endl;
    cout << var2 << endl;

    fsDemo.release();
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    return 0;
    }
```

I have tried with XML as well, the output is just empty []. I wonder why. Any assistance is much appreciate. Thanks[image]

Comment: Are you sure `"C:\\faceData\\demo.yaml"` is the correct path? Please double check it.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Ya, I am 100% sure. The path is the correct one. Check many times, in fact I have located the demo.yaml solely to the same directory with the executable file and try with "demo.yaml";. I just wonder will there be a problem if I use visual studio to do the compilation? Thanks